# Pandas Module Not Found even though it's installed

Tags: python, conda

I am using anaconda for this. I have downloaded pandas using both:

```
pip install pandas
```

and

```
conda install pandas
```

They successfully install, and doing the installation again shows that they are already installed. However, when writing this line alone

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? You may have installed Pandas in a different version.

Comment: Uh... I’m not sure if I accidentally downloaded the 32-bit version when I was originally getting it, I don’t think so, but maybe that’s what happened. How can I check to see if that’s the case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the conda environment where pandas was installed? For example, if you created the env using `conda env create -n myenv`, then running the following before installing the package should help:

```
conda activate myenv
```

Where is pandas installed? If using linux you could try to run

```
locate "pandas/__init__.py"
```

to find where you have some copy of pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necesarilly need an environment for this. 
The real deal with this problem is to know what `pip` or `conda` you are actually using and then on which `python` will the stuff be installed.

You can open python and:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Like this you can know where your python is. Go to that folder and you'll also find a `pip`.

Then you have two options:

1) Set this path on your environments variables => you won't ever have the problem unless you try to do *another* python installation (then yes, use conda environment )

2) In you command prompt `your/pip/path/pip install pandas`

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely dumb about these kinds of things. Could you please explain how to set the file path on the environment's variables (or maybe just what you mean by that)? Also, when I did "sys,path", I got many file paths, so instead I searched for pip on my quick search and found the file path for pip.exe that way. Is this fine, or do I need a different "pip" file?

Comment: You should have got to the same folder with `sys.path`  :) my worry is that you may have more than one `pip.exe` that's a very common problem . It is important that this folder contains the same `python.exe` that is used by anaconda. About the environment variables as you are using windows you can just search for "environment variables" and you'll find how to change them. These variables link certain commands to certain paths, for example that's how windows knows where to search when you type `pip` in the command prompt