# Won't import downloaded library

Tags: python, import, pip

I'm following a tutorial on a web scraper in python and it uses the module "textblob" I pip installed it using "pip install textblob" and it downloaded. then in the code I have `from textblob import TextBlob` and when it runs it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'`. But when I run it in command prompt it imports perfectly this is kinda confusing. I'm not using and virtual environments. Can someone please explain to me why this isn't importing correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Is `textblob` installed in the same environment as you are using or is it installed in the base environment ? if you are using an virtual environment, you will have activate your environment and then run `pip install textblob`

Answer (score 0):

It is very very likely that you have multiple instances of Python and pip in your computer. Therefore you may have installed textblob in a different instance. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950452/11261546) a couple of things you should consider.

In general you should know where your pip is and where the python you are using is (lifelike not the same place)

Comment: Thank you, I do not know if that was the issue or not (I'm assuming it was) I just ended up reinstall python and it worked but thanks!