# why I got ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ModuleName' ) error in VSCode, windows 10?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, modulenotfounderror

I wrote a simple python program that I learned from Mosh Hamedani course.

- Operating System: Windows10, 64bit
- Editor: VSCode
- Python: 3.9.0

[image: Installed Pythons]

1- I created a folder called "PyCrawler".

2- Then in my project directory, using terminal, run these commands one by one:

```
  pipenv install beautifulsoup4

  pipenv install requests
```

3- Then it give me an error to install autopep8, so I installed that.

4- created a file named "app.py"

5- selected correspond venv.

6- write these code inside app.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

questions = soup.select(".question-summary")
print(questions[0].select_one(".question-hyperlink").getText())
```

7- when I run this program using "python app.py" command it gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' " error.

[image: a screenshot from the error that I got]

It's strange. I installed beautifulsoup4, why I got this error?!!

Solutions in other questions that have been asked didn't help me.

I got same issue for selenium.

I think if I install any package I get this issue and I don't know why.

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: it's quite likely that you have more than one python intallation, try printing the actual path using VSCode and [somthing like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950452/11261546)

Comment: Try `pip3env` to install the dependencies. Because you using python version 3

Comment: did the path of your intallation matrch with the path you printed with `sys.path` ?

Comment: @Ivan  when I'm in my project folder in VSCode, I commented out all code and import sys and print(sys.path), it show me ... (next comment)

Comment: ['path to my project', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages'] 
I think they are paths to original python that I've installed on my machine, not python in venv.

Comment: maybe try install  `pipenv install bs4`

Comment: @Zighol check with below link to sove your issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup

Comment: pipenv install bs4 did not solve the issue. now I'm sure it's not specific to a package, so please consider this. installing requests package and then import that throw the same issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably installing the packages to a different version of Python than the one you are using to run your program. Before you run your program, enter the command

```sh
$ pipenv shell
```

into your terminal to activate the enviornment. Then

```sh
$ python app.py
```

should work. For more information, see the [documentation for pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html).

Comment: " pipenv shell " solved my problem. Thanks a lot.